# Onto of compositions of onto functions when function is define

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have two functions, $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = 2x - 3$ $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  If both of these functions are onto, how can we show that $g\circ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is onto?

$ f: X \rightarrow Y$ onto means $$\forall y \in Y, \exists x \in X \text{ such that } f(x) = y$$

Comment: Can you recall the definition of "onto"? That will tell us how to check whether functions are onto or not.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I just updated the question with the definition,

Comment: Excellent, $+1$ for your efforts. Now, we want to prove that $g \circ f$ is onto. For this, we want to prove $\forall y, \exists x , f(x) = y$. So, start with $y \in \mathbb R$. Since $f$ is onto, there is some $z \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(z) = y$. Now since $g$ is onto, ...?

Answer (score 1):

Show h:R -> R is onto iff h(R) = R.
To show gf is onto, show gf(R) = g(R) = R.